# Resignation Letter- In Person vs Email?

Tags: professionalism, resignation

I have accepted a new position at another job opportunity. I currently work two places and am planning to leave one for this new position. I only work a few days a week (clients depending) at the location I plan on leaving and as of right now don't have anything for next week. Im trying to meet with the owner to give this letter but she tells me via email she cant meet at the times I suggusted and we can talk via phone if I want.

would it be unprofessional or burn bridges per say If I just wrote an email explaining what I would have in person and attaching the letter or resignation. Or should I postpone giving the letter until a time we can finally agree on a time. (possibly 6 days later)

Comment: Prepare the letter at the very least. If it's really 6 days of waiting, phone your superior to inform them in a polite way, then an email should be sufficient. Keep it short and sweet and don't feel pressured into anything. Goo luck with the new job. :)

Comment: Can you please add a country tag? Where I live, resignation by email is not even a valid way to resign.

Answer (score 4):

In my experience in the US, the news that you are resigning is delivered *synchronously*. The problem with resigning by email is that you're sending it off to be read at an unknown later time. It is far better to have a (short) conversstion.

If your manager isn't available to meet in person, a phone call beats email. Once you deliver the news your manager might arrange an in-person meeting, but meanwhile you have given notice without days of delay and in a way that allows conversation.  *After* you have the conversation, you can send the letter by email (just as, for an in-person conversation, you would hand over a physical letter).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's unprofessional. I think phoning may be an easier option but waiting 6 days seems too long. I think by indicating that you want to leave you may find they make some time to meet with you and talk about it

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to give it by email even if you discuss it by phone later (e.g. to make sure they got it) - email has the benefit of a time-stamp on it, so if there are any disputes regarding your notice period, the email knows when you gave your notice. It's also a permanent account of what was said which could be used to resolve any other misunderstandings, in a way that a phone call cannot.

Comment: To add I would use my work email (so they immediately know who you are) to send it & cc my personal email to have that copy in case there's a potential issue and I'm locked out of the employer's email or something.